# How can I use an oracle keyword as an alias?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like use the following sql statement in my code:

```
SELECT ..., DATA.EXT_ID AS NUMBER, ... FROM DATA;
```

But I can't since "NUMBER" is a keyword.
Is there any way around this?
Thanks!

Comment: Where are the duplicates? I searched around but didn't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes around the keyword:

```
SELECT DATA.EXT_ID AS "NUMBER" FROM DATA;
```